# Eval Change the value

Tags: asp.net, eval, dataitem

How can I do change Order Status field.
For example ; I want do if the data name "AÇIK" change name "OPEN". How can I do.

```
   <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"OrderStatus") %></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<%#(DataBinder.Eval(Container, "OrderStatus").ToString()=="AÇIK") ? 
             "OPEN":DataBinder.Eval(Container, "OrderStatus")%>
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I do more than one For example "AÇIK" "OPEN" "KAPALI" "CLOSE" "MUSTERI" "CUSTOMER"

Comment: I want to do below. How can I do <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"OfferStatus").ToString() == "ACIK" ? "BEKLEMEDE" : 
         DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"OfferStatus").ToString() == "KAPALI" ? "ONAYLANDI" :
          DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"OfferStatus").ToString() == "MUSTERI_ONAY" ? "ONAYLANMADI" : "ONAYLANMADI" %></td>

Comment: Hi can anyone help me please ?

Comment: @AliYılmaz What you have mentioned in the `comment` should work as you expected.

Comment: I want to do below. How can I do <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"OfferStatus").ToString() == "ACIK" ? "BEKLEMEDE" : DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"OfferStatus").ToString() == "KAPALI" ? "ONAYLANDI" : DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"OfferStatus").ToString() == "MUSTERI_ONAY" ? "ONAYLANMADI" : "ONAYLANMADI" %></td>

Comment: @AliYılmaz It looks fine.Are you getting any error??